# maven override profile from parent in child

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I have a multi-module maven project.

```
parent-module-->child-submodule1
             \->child-submodule2
```

Children are both submodules AND children of parent-module.

Child-submodule1 has a build profile my-profile very specific that should be shared with his sibling (submodule 2) as it setup the environment for both.

I moved this "my-profile" to the parent.
Now when I build activating this profile it is executed three times, thus the build fails (as this profile does very specific things here).

I needed the profile to be executed only once in the parent, and being skipped in the children.
I tried removing the parent-children relationship and this way it woud work, but I have other problems to solve (dependencies carried out from the parent).

How can I do it?
Can I override the profile in the children deactivating it?

Comment: You seem to contradict yourself. You say "Child-submodule1 has a build profile my-profile very specific that should be shared with his sibling (submodule 2) as it setup the environment for both.", but later your move the profile to parent and don't want it to be executed in child modules? It would help if you could give us some insight what exactly happens in your profile.

Comment: actually submodule2 has been added after submodule1: they both perform integration testing on Jboss. submodule2 need to have the same environment as submodule1. 
Until submodule2 did not exist I did not need to have the profile moved up. 
I could keep the profile in the submodule 1, but this way the submodule 2 build would be dependent from submodule 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot deactivate a profile in children or prevent it from run.

You could however set `<inherited>false</inherited>` on all executions in `my-profile` in parent.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can active the profile using one of these methods:

1. Having an activation policy of a specific property value only set on the two sub modules

> ```
> <profiles>
>   <profile>
>     <activation>
>       <property>
>         <name>doit</name>
>         <value>true</value>
>       </property>
>     </activation>
>     ...
>   </profile>
> </profiles>
> ```

1. Using the presence of a specific file or folder, which is probably in your scenario anyway.

> ```
> <profiles>
>   <profile>
>     <activation>
>       <file>
>         <exists>src/main/xcopy</exists>
>       </file>
>     </activation>
>     ...
>   </profile>
> </profiles>
> ```